# Codeigniter dynamic dropdown wierdness

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I saw that there are a lot of questions about dynamic dropdowns so I will hope that mine won't be glossed over. I have this method in a model that draws data from a table and creates an array for use to build a codeigniter dropdown. 

 `// method in the model
 public function house_dropdown()
 {
      $dbres = $this->db->get('house'); //used php5 method chaining
       //cycle through result and create array to be made a drop down.
      $dbarray = array();
      foreach($dbres->result_array() as $db)
      {
         $dbarray[$db['house_id']] = $db['house_name'];
       }
         return $dbarray;
}`

This creates the array and is consumed in a controller and sent to a view like so:

 `$this->data['house'] = $this->gen_model->house_dropdown();
 $this->template->set($this->data)
                       ->set_partial('maincontent','partials/maincontent/admin/register')
                       ->build('layouts/default');`

// creates a from element like so
 echo form_dropdown($house);

But this is the error I get right at the point of the dropdown element:

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Illegal offset type in isset or empty
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
Line Number: 319
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
Line Number: 329`

so I am stumped! Cos I am not sure where to look since I know that the form helper cannot have errors and in my code I don't see anything. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS. I did a var dump on the $dbarray after the foreach and it shows that the array was populated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have passed wrong number of parameters to  the function, it should be

```
echo form_dropdown('name_of_the_dropdown', $house, 'current_selected_item');
```

From `codeigniter` documentations

```
$options = array(
     'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
     'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
     'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
     'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
 );

$shirts_on_sale = array('small', 'large');

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');
```

Would produce:

```
<select name="shirts">
    <option value="small">Small Shirt</option>
    <option value="med">Medium Shirt</option>
    <option value="large" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
    <option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

**Reference:** [**Form Helper**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: Heera, thanks I think its just lots of coffee I am sorry for such a simple mistake